# RxJava2 observable not processing onNext when there is a change

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am beginner in RxJava. 
I want to track changes of the `Int` variable and react to it when it changes.

Here is my example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var button: Button
    var counter: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val observable :Observable<Int> = Observable.just(counter)

        button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            counter++
        })


        observable.subscribe(
                Consumer { t ->
                    Log.d("fromObservable", counter.toString()) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

However, the Log never invokes when I click the button. 
How can I make it properly with RxJava2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a simple observable only emitting one element, but you can use a `Subject` for your use-case:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var button: Button
    var counter: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val subject: BehaviorSubject<Int> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(counter)
        val observable: Observable<Int> = subject.hide()

        button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            subject.onNext(++counter)
        })

        observable.subscribe(
                Consumer { t ->
                    Log.d("fromObservable", counter.toString()) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating your `Observable` correctly.

`Observable.just(counter)` will create an `Observable` that emit the value of `counter` and complete. [Documentation of Observable.just()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/just.html)

You can do what you want with a `Subject` like `BehaviorSubject`. [Documentation of Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var button: Button

    var counter : Int = 0
        set(value) {
            field = value
            observable.onNext(value)
        }
    val observable : BehaviorSubject<Int> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(counter)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            counter++
        })

        observable.subscribe(
                Consumer { t ->
                    Log.d("fromObservable", counter.toString()) }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use it directly with the property, consider using an observable delegate though.